# Using a parent site calculated field as a lookup source

Tags: lookup-column, filter, calculated-column, sub-site

How can I achieve the following:

I have a parent site with a Contacts List. There are columns for "First name" and "Last name", and I made a calculated column called "Full name" to display them both together using CONCATENATE, with the result as a text string.

In a subsite I want to lookup contacts using the "Full name" column from the parent. How can I achieve this?

As an extra layer, would I be able to filter the lookup column's options by a third field in the Contacts list? For instance, only showing the names of people where the field Job Title = "Manager".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Site Settings

Under Galleries select Site Columns

Click Create at the top of the list

Give the column a title you will reference in your "child" lists

Select Lookup as the column type

Select the site's column group to categorize the new column

Select the list to lookup from the "Get information from" dropdown

Select the column of the lookup list you want to reference as the key in your "child" lists

Example: "Title (linked to item)" so that you can easily reference the parent item from your child list item
Click OK

From the All Items list vies, select Settings > List Settings

At the end of the Columns list select Add from existing site columns

You can filter the selections by selecting the group you associated the parent column with from the dropdown

Select the site column you created above and click the Add button

Click OK

Comment: This worked! Thanks! For some reason, I couldn't choose the Calculated parent field as the Lookup Target in Sharepoint deisgner 2013, but it worked editing through the browser as you suggested.

Comment: @MarkE, you now click garvon-77 answer as the correct one.. He gets credit, you get credit, and the question is marked as having a valuable answer so gets better ranking in search results